# Skip exec-maven-plugin from Command Line Argument in Maven

Tags: maven, plugins, execution, skip

By default in my project POM, `exec-maven-plugin, rpm-maven-plugin` will be executed,
which is not required in local compilation/build.

I want to skip these plugin execution by passing Command Line Arguments
I tried below command to skip them like normal plugins, but didn't work though!

> mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.exec.skip=true
>   -Dmaven.rpm.skip=true

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Starting with version 1.4.0 the former name `skip` has been changed into `exec.skip`.

This [page](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#skip) should tell you that the name of the argument to be passed by cmdline (i.e. the user property) was called `skip`, which was a poorly chosen name. To fix this you could do the following:

```
<properties>
  <maven.exec.skip>false</maven.exec.skip> <!-- default -->
</properties>
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <skip>${maven.exec.skip}</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: thanks for that. somehow I missed that. Can you please tell me for rpm-maven-plugin too? I have seen their project page, couldn't find anything :(

Comment: rpm-maven-plugin doesn't have a skip property, that's why you can't find it. AFAIK the rpm is the end/package result, so I wonder if it makes sense to skip it. IMHO, most of the time if you need to skip things, it's a sign that either your process or your pom structure/hierarchy is incorrect.

Comment: It doesn't work in local Macbook. RPM plugin still has issues with mac os and I just want to skip for local builds

Comment: In that case, move the rpm-maven-plugin to a profile (http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Activation) with activation `<os><family>!mac</family></os>`, see also http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireOS.html . Even though I often write that profiles are often misused, since this is an OS specific request, a profile is allowed. And since it's all open source, why not contact the mojo team and try to fix it for Mac as well.

Answer (score 16):

Try `-Dexec.skip` from specification:

http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#skip

Answer (score 5):

Using profiles (as little as possible) and execution phase you may achieve what you want for plugins that do not handle the skip property:

Plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>${rpmPackagePhase}</phase>
            <id>generate-rpm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>rpm</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
    ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Profile configuration:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <rpmPackagePhase>none</rpmPackagePhase>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>rpmPackage</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>rpm.package</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <rpmPackagePhase>package</rpmPackagePhase>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Invocation:

```
mvn package -Drpm.package=true [...]
```